# How to add a bit value to a field for multiple records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, binary, bit

Have a database where one table has a field that uses binary bits as flags.  So depending on which flags are toggled, you could have a wide range of values so looking at the value alone isn't helpful.  ie, a value greater than 8 doesn't mean that the value of 8 is in use (17 for example is 16 + 1).

With this in mind, is there a way to update multiple records to either set or unset a bit (say a value of 8) for a particular field?  Some records might have it set while others don't, so don't want to just simple add (or subtract) 8 from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [BIT functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html). To set bit 1:

```
update your_table
set bit_field = bit_field | b'0001'
```

To unset bit 1:

```
update your_table
set bit_field = bit_field & b'1110'
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14ebf/1)

Comment: So | adds the bit and & only keeps matching bits (set to 1)?

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, for unsetting, would ^ be a better alternative?

* Marked yours as the answer since you answered first.  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, tried the demo link and see that & is the way to go.  Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Wolfie `& ~` is what you'll want to use for unsetting. `^` will flip the bits every time and not reliably set/unset.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the bitwise OR `|` and AND `&` functions;

```
UPDATE myTable SET myValue = value |  8;   -- set bit 3
UPDATE myTable SET myValue = value & ~8;   -- clear bit 3
```

[(Very) simple SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ead7/1).